# OpenVPN server does not provide access to internet

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I am able to connect to my newly installed OpenVPN server (Debian 6.0 VPS using OpenVZ).

When connected with the windows client, I am not able to access the internet. `net.ipv4.ip_forward` and `iptables` are enabled and the necessary reboot for these changes where made.

How can I get the access to work? Can someone help me out? I could imagine, that I used wrong IP adresses when configuring OpenVPN, but how can i verify those in case this might be the issue?

My server.conf: http://pastebin.com/TtbNgdaG

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN has nothing to do with connecting to the internet and everything to do with connecting to your local LAN.

Once you connect to your LAN, OpenVPN will configure routes to your LAN in whatever way you configured OpenVPN even if they conflict with existing routes. For instance, your computer may be on 10.0.0.x and your OpenVPN may be on 10.0.0.x. As soon as you connect, OpenVPN would change your GW for 10.0.0.x to your OpenVPN gw.

Oh bam! You just created a network loop and with that all the brains that previously existed in your very intelligent network card went up in a puff of smoke. Sad ;(.

Comment: Well, but I want to use the vpn connection to my vps to use the internet connection of my vps, which of cause is possible. Due to the IPs you chose, I think you looked into the server.conf of mine, don't you? Are you telling me, that I indeed used wrong IP adresses? How do I choose the right ones? These might be stupid questions but I am new to these network 'things' and did not fully got to the bottom of it.