# openvpn client connects to server but name resolution does not work

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn

Here is my (x)ubuntu version:

```
root@ubuntu:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

network-manager has been purged; I made an apt-clean after desinstallation. you need network-manager-openvpn package when running openvpn with network-manager

Before I mount the vpn, here is what we have:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:01:ee:91:3d  
          inet addr:192.168.2.79  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:1ff:feee:913d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:442 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:628026 (628.0 KB)  TX bytes:56869 (56.8 KB)
```

Ping is filtered by the ISP:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (64.233.167.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Prohibited
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Net Prohibited
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Net Prohibited
```

I can ping the stack:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ping 192.168.02.79
PING 192.168.02.79 (192.168.2.79) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.79: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.79: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
```

I installed client configuration from a free VPN provider here is the client configuration:

```
client
dev tun1
proto tcp
remote 93.115.83.250 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
fast-io
pull
route-delay 2
redirect-gateway
###---I just added the following: ----
verb 6
```

I connect to the vpn server:

```
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=990883 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=990952 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=992665 LZO compression initialized
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=992867 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1560 D:140 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=992969 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=993035 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1560 D:1450 EF:60 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=993091 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1560,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=993113 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1560,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=993170 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'bc07730e'
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=993211 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'b695cb4a'
Thu Dec  4 15:16:36 2014 us=993259 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443 [nonblock]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:37 2014 us=993523 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443
Thu Dec  4 15:16:37 2014 us=993596 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:37 2014 us=993625 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443
Thu Dec  4 15:16:37 2014 us=993748 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=90125 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [26] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=90205 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443, sid=c7148944 7465b88f
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=90260 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 0 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=90329 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=90360 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=90385 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=90409 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [39] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=3 DATA len=25
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=320860 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=454622 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 2 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=454685 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [126] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 3 ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=454770 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=454791 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=3 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=454812 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=4 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=454833 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=454882 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [30] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 2 3 4 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=550166 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=5 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=550236 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 5 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=647096 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=6 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=647160 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 6 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=742280 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=7 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=742347 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=8 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=742399 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 7 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=742419 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 8 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=836052 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=9 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=836258 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 9 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=929756 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=10 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:38 2014 us=929826 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 10 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=23949 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=11 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=24066 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=12 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=24098 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 11 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=24124 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 12 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=117875 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=13 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=117994 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 13 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=212512 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=14 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=212671 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 14 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=307308 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=15 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=307424 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=16 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=307456 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 15 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=307483 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 16 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=401580 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=17 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=401755 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 17 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=496062 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=18 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=496182 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 18 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=591394 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=19 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=591551 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=20 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=591628 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 19 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=591691 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 20 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=687983 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=21 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=688097 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 21 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=782779 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=22 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=782866 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 22 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=877451 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=23 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=877607 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=24 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=877683 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 23 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=877812 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 24 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=971340 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=25 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:39 2014 us=971458 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 25 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=65227 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=26 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=65346 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 26 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=160165 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=27 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=161894 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=MT, ST=MLT, L=Valletta, O=FreeVPN.me, OU=FreeVPN.me, CN=FreeVPN.me CA, name=FreeVPN.me, emailAddress=contact@freevpn.me
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=163344 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=MT, ST=MLT, L=Valletta, O=FreeVPN.me, OU=FreeVPN.me, CN=FreeVPN.me, name=FreeVPN.me, emailAddress=contact@freevpn.me
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=163472 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=28 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=163551 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 27 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=163616 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 28 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=253396 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=29 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=253509 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 29 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=347870 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=30 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=347990 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 30 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=441661 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=31 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=441820 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=32 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=441897 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 31 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=441961 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 32 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=537084 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=33 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=537156 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 33 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=631310 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=34 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=631481 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 34 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=724912 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [103] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=35 DATA len=89
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=779076 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [126] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 35 ] pid=4 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=779109 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=5 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=779129 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=6 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=779149 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [40] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=7 DATA len=26
Thu Dec  4 15:16:40 2014 us=956873 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 4 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=89394 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 5 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=89581 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 6 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=89642 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [126] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 7 ] pid=36 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=89717 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=37 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=89954 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [48] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=38 DATA len=34
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=90276 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 36 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=90385 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [130] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 37 38 ] pid=8 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=90433 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=9 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=90505 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [114] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=10 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=90548 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [92] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=11 DATA len=78
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=322864 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 8 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=454411 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 9 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=454575 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 10 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=454623 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [126] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ 11 ] pid=39 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=454730 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=40 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=454778 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [96] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=41 DATA len=82
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=455128 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=455157 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=455180 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=455254 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=455302 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 39 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=455404 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [26] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 40 41 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=455459 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Thu Dec  4 15:16:41 2014 us=455541 [FreeVPN.me] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443
Thu Dec  4 15:16:43 2014 us=814138 SENT CONTROL [FreeVPN.me]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Thu Dec  4 15:16:43 2014 us=814256 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [104] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=12 DATA len=90
Thu Dec  4 15:16:43 2014 us=911787 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [22] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 12 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=51636 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=42 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=51861 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [114] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=43 DATA len=100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=51915 TCPv4_CLIENT READ [48] from [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=44 DATA len=34
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=52032 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.13.0.1,topology net30,ping 15,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.13.0.94 10.13.0.93'
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=52202 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=52224 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=52242 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=52258 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=52563 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.2.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlan0 HWADDR=00:24:01:ee:91:3d
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=53073 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=53110 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=53142 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=53207 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=55739 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.13.0.94 peer 10.13.0.93
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=56888 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 42 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:44 2014 us=57018 TCPv4_CLIENT WRITE [26] to [AF_INET]93.115.83.250:443: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 43 44 ]
Thu Dec  4 15:16:46 2014 us=237316 /sbin/ip route add 93.115.83.250/32 via 192.168.2.1
Thu Dec  4 15:16:46 2014 us=238627 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.13.0.93
Thu Dec  4 15:16:46 2014 us=240611 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.13.0.93
Thu Dec  4 15:16:46 2014 us=243113 /sbin/ip route add 10.13.0.1/32 via 10.13.0.93
Thu Dec  4 15:16:46 2014 us=245592 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

The vpn is now mounted:

```
tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.13.0.94  P-t-P:10.13.0.93  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Here is the routing table when vpn is in place:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.13.0.93      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.13.0.1       10.13.0.93      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
10.13.0.93      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
93.115.83.250   192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
128.0.0.0       10.13.0.93      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip route show
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.13.0.93 dev tun1 
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 
10.13.0.1 via 10.13.0.93 dev tun1 
10.13.0.93 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.13.0.94 
93.115.83.250 via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.13.0.93 dev tun1 
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.79
```

I can ping the stack:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping 10.13.0.94
PING 10.13.0.94 (10.13.0.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.13.0.94: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from 10.13.0.94: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
```

I can ping the vpn server:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping 10.13.0.1
PING 10.13.0.1 (10.13.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.13.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=96.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.13.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=99.6 ms
```

I cannot ping the tunnel end host (which is normal):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping 10.13.0.93
PING 10.13.0.93 (10.13.0.93) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.13.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Prohibited
From 10.13.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Prohibited
```

I can ping any ip on internet through the tunnel:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping 212.27.40.240 
PING 212.27.40.240 (212.27.40.240) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 212.27.40.240: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=138 ms
64 bytes from 212.27.40.240: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=137 ms
64 bytes from 212.27.40.240: icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=137 ms

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping 173.194.44.18
PING 173.194.44.18 (173.194.44.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.194.44.18: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=140 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.44.18: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=1722 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.44.18: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=809 ms
```

I can ping both dns provided by the vpn

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=133 ms


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping 8.8.4.4
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=128 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=127 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=128 ms
```

I made a little dump to be sure the tunnel is used when pinging an ip over internet:

```
root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump -ni any icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol dec ode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
11:18:12.091704 IP 10.13.0.94 > 212.27.40.240: ICMP echo request, id 6625, seq 1, length 64
11:18:12.227045 IP 212.27.40.240 > 10.13.0.94: ICMP echo reply, id 6625, seq 1, length 64
11:18:13.093187 IP 10.13.0.94 > 212.27.40.240: ICMP echo request, id 6625, seq 2, length 64
11:18:13.228153 IP 212.27.40.240 > 10.13.0.94: ICMP echo reply, id 6625, seq 2, length 64
11:18:14.094211 IP 10.13.0.94 > 212.27.40.240: ICMP echo request, id 6625, seq 3,
```

dump above shows there is no routing issue as well.

but I cannot resolve anything:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nslookup www.google.com 8.8.4.4
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

tcpdump shows that the dns requests are sent, but we never see any response back to our requests:

```
root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump -ni any port 53
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
15:31:42.213105 IP 10.13.0.94.36335 > 8.8.8.8.53: 55836+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:31:47.213243 IP 10.13.0.94.36335 > 8.8.8.8.53: 55836+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:31:52.213427 IP 10.13.0.94.36335 > 8.8.8.8.53: 55836+ A? www.google.com. (32)
```

No filter is in place:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

iptables not installed

I dont think it's a routing problem, because ping to an internet ip or to the dns ips (of the vpn) gets back normally.

I checked syslog but did not find any vpn related logs.

I have tried another free vpn provider and have the exact same problem.

I have digged over and over again through google but could not find any accetable answer or lead. It starts becoming insame at this point, because I start doing the same tests over and over and dont know what to do.

the posts I have already read in stackoverflow:

No internet on OpenVPN connection -> the solution is to put 'push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8" ' in the server conf. As for me, this option appears in the debug output when starting the client.

OpenVPN + iptables: not forwarding traffic -> it's a server related issue + iptables rules.

(SOLVED) OpenVPN - Ubuntu network manager connection ok, but not resolving, not pinging, no internet -> this one looked very interesting, but dns issue was solved with dnsmasq command on the vps.

https://superuser.com/questions/717383/vpn-dns-resolution -> I think this is a server related issue.

[OpenVPN server does not provide access to internet](https://superuser.com/questions/701723/openvpn-server-does-not-provide-access-to-internet) -> no solution provided, but I guess this is more an iptables (forwarding option) or server related issue.

I sent a mail to both vpn providers but no answer after more than 2 days.

any idea? thank you so much folks.

Answer (score 26):

Ubuntu does magic stuff with DNS, but fortunately OpenVPN provides a way to deal with that. If you've installed openvpn from the Ubuntu repositories, you'll have a script in /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf to tell Ubuntu what DNS it should use for your vpn connection. To use it, add the following lines to your openvpn configuration file:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

That will run the script when your VPN connection comes up and goes down, and will update the DNS settings accordingly.

*Edit (20-06-2018):*
As @Thenightmanager mentions in the comments, modern Ubuntu (at least 18.04 and newer) introduced some extra systemd DNS magic, and the update-resolv-conf script might no longer suffice.  Check out [update-systemd-resolved](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved) for a possible working alternative.

Comment: thank you Steffan; I know this script, I normally use it to avoid dns leaks; I have used it for the present issue in vain. But I will try again and will come back with an answer.

Comment: I add 

script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf

to my client config
I can ping the stack: 
I can ping the vpn serveR, DNS, external IPs


but cannot resolve

nslookup www.google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

 nslookup www.google.com 8.8.4.4
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Been fighting with MTU's and everything for a while now.  Stumbled upon this gem and fixed my problem.  Thanks for the answer it worked for my issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip, it was immensely useful to me in the past. Note that on Ubuntu 18.04 (and perhaps already on Ubuntu 17.04) `update-systemd-resolved` should be used instead of `update-resolv-conf`.

Comment: Thanks the [`update-systemd-resolved`](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved) script worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 I used the update-systemd-resolved script and modified the /etc/hosts file for the name resolution. I am using nslookup to find the ip addresses, for now.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that some form of NAT **must** take place for DNS (or any internet data) to work over a VPN.  Typically:
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

However, You state:

> iptables not installed

If this is so then your Server LAN router **must** perform NAT and have a static route for your VPN pointed at your VPN server IP.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with Ubuntu 15 and OpenVPN 2.3.2: the "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8" is not taken into account by the client.

My solution was to use the Network Management Framework (+openvpn plugin) to setup the VPN. But again, the "dhcp-option DNS" is not taken into account, so I added 8.8.8.8 manually in "IPV4 settings / DNS servers". Only then I can see in the log:

> NetworkManager[786]:    Internal DNS: 8.8.8.8
>
> dnsmasq[1020]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53