# Open vpn - ping by ip works, ns doesn't

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have recently installed my own OpenVPN server on digital ocean following this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

I tried playing with the following option:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

When it is commented out, my original IP is visible, when this option is on, I can only ssh or ping servers by ip, but cannot by any means get their name servers resolved.

I tried all the solutions offered here:
[openvpn client connects to server but name resolution does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/849234/openvpn-client-connects-to-server-but-name-resolution-does-not-work/1130535#1130535)

But unfortunately nothing worked.

Server: Ubuntu 16.04 @ Digital Ocean
Client: tried both Viscosity and TunnelBlick (OSX El Capitan)

Comment: Is "bypass-dchp" strictly necessary in this instance?

Comment: Otherwise my original up is visible as I noted, thus Von does not work

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, does [push "redirect-gateway def1"] without the "bypass-dchp" element help?

Comment: Trying now let me see

Comment: Hold on, are you referring to google's DNS server there? If so, DCHP and DNS are very different things - DCHP is required to automatically provide IP addresses to things that connect to your VPN server, DNS is to turn "www.google.com" into its IP address for computers to understand and use.

Comment: push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
Added it only after defaults did not work

Comment: Anyhow I reverted to a backup I had of the file with the original servers:
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

without the `override-dhcp` option and the result is still the same :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46182/discussion-between-sam3000-and-oleg-tikhonov).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but if your current DNS servers are assigned by your ISP for example, they will stop resolving domains for you when your VPN is up. Because your public IP address changed, your ISP no longer recognizes you as one of their customers. Rationale: your queries come from an IP address that doesn't belong to them.

If you use an open DNS resolver like Google (8.8.8.8) this should work.

You should check which name servers are current defined on your client. Depending on your OS you may have to tweak network settings, the OpenVPN config will not always be able to 'push' the desired settings to the client.

Here is a link that describes the problem and how to fix it with an up/down script: [OpenVPN DNS resolution not working](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=21678)

On a Linux platform this command should tell you which name servers are currently active:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

You can test with nslookup or dig. for example type:

```
nslookup
```

And then:

```
server x.x.x.x  -> where x.x.x.x is the IP address of the name server your want to test
```

And then type a domain name ie. superuser.com and see the results.

Comment: Added that one to the server, did not work unfortunately, I did my share of googling

Comment: Also tried some client side hook which did not work either

Comment: Ok it is solved, any idea how to do it automatically?